# Change height of chartjs dynamically

Tags: css, angular, height, chart.js

I'm using Angular 5 with Chartjs. I have a chart where I want the height to change depending on a boolean variable (show). If true, I want the height to be 25. If false I want the height to be 65. I tried this but it doesn't work. How do I change the height conditionally?

```
<div  [hidden]="!chart" style="position: relative; float: left; ">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="{show ? '25':'65'}">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: How about ``[height.px]="show ? 25 : 65"``?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong syntax.

```
height="{show ? '25':'65'}"
```

I assume you are mixing it up with React. In Angular, first you need to wrap the name of the prop in `[]`, like `[height]`, and on the right you simply specify a JavaScript expression (you do not wrap it in `{}`).

```
[height]="show ? '25px' : '65px'"
```

You also have to specify units.

If you don't want to specify units, there's an alternative way to do it:

```
[height.px]="show ? 25 : 65"
```

Comment: From my understanding, the height and width are given by chartjs as a ratio (height/width in px will be calculated based on the window). Is there a way to use the height attribute provided by chartjs and change the ratio depending on the variable show?